# ngx-extended-pdf-viewer Disable scrolling to searched text

Tags: angular, pdf.js, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I am working on an application where I have pins right next to the PDF and when I hover on the pin it should highlight some text, I am currently using the search API provided by this library to search and highlight the text when the user hovers on the PDF pin but this has the added effect of scrolling to the highlighted text which I want to disable but I can't find anything about this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm planning to implement a similar feature soon (https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/issues/832). Maybe I could also add the "no scroll" feature. I suggest you add your feature request to the ticket, or open a new ticket.